# My database isn't accepting 'name' property

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am trying to pass in **"name"** in my **"friends"** through my controller. 
I have already made a **"names"** table with names in it 
I keep getting **"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"** This error.

**Here's my FriendsController:-**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Friend;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Name;

class FriendsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {   

        $name = Name::all()->random(1)[0]->name;


        Friend::create([
            'my_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'friends_id'=>$request->friends_id,
            'name' => $name->name,
        ]);

        Friend::create([
            'friends_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'my_id'=>$request->friends_id,
            'name' => $name->name,
        ]);

        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

**Here's my friends table:-**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('my_id');
        $table->string('friends_id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();     
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Here's My Names table:-**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('names', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Instead of loading every `Name` to a Collection using `::all()`, try with `Name::inRandomOrder()->first()->name;`. Beyond that, don't use `'name' => $name->name,` as you're already calling `->name` above (which is a string), so you're basically doing `'name' => $name->name->name`, which ain't gonna work.

Comment: so what do you recommend i should use in create method?

Comment: `'name' => $name`. That's it.

Comment: yes, i tried this before but it doesn't pass in the data present in the name variable, It now did.. thaks alott

Comment: did you try to use other properties like the `id` for example ? and also can you share the rows in the names table ?

Comment: @Mahmood Ahmad Thanks for the effort but I got my answer

Comment: Great to know that your problem is solved! l encourage you to post the answer to your question.

Comment: @Mahmood Ahmad I have posted the answer u can check it.

Comment: Great! So when someone faces the same problem he/she can find the solution.

Comment: would you mind helping me out with another problenm

Comment: Ok, what is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62073778/chatbox-notification-not-wroking

Comment: this is the problem

Comment: Ok thanks for sharing, l will check it out by today as l'm using the cell phone by now

Comment: Okhay..plese do check it as soon as possible. *-Thanks For Your Time*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's The Solution:-**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{   

    $name = Name::inRandomOrder()->first()->name;


    Friend::create([
    'my_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
    'friends_id'=>$request->friends_id,
    'name' => $name,
]);

    Friend::create([
    'friends_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
    'my_id'=>$request->friends_id,
    'name' => $name,
]);

     return redirect('/home');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`'name' => $name` should be correct as Tim mentioned. If it wasn't saved into your database, it was probably because `name` column is guarded in your model.

Try adding `protected $guarded=['id'];` or  `protected $fillable=['name'];`in your Friend Model and see if that works. To know more about this, You can check laravel's [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment). Cheers :)